# Android Throw Exception

Tags: android, exception, throw

In my application, I use `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and it has `insertOrThrow` method. I want to learn that will this method close my connection before throw an exception? And it is written on definition of method that "the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred "

When throw an exception how it has a return value? Something is wrong. Explanation or throw ?

This is how I use `InsertOrThrow`.
I want to know when I declare `throws Exception` to my method, is it necessary to use `try-catch` (If I don't have any special thing to do in catch like my exp.)?

```
public long insert(ContentValues cv) throws Exception {
    try
    {
        long rowId = getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow(_tableName, null, cv);
        return rowId;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally{
        Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your practical stuff you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends; if `this.Close()` can throw an exception, then it still needs to be declared as being thrown, or caught. Often times this is wrapped up in a small utility method.

It's not *mandatory* to use a `catch`, you can simply `try`/`finally`.

Regarding return values: methods that exit due to an exception don't have a return value.

Exceptions should encapsulate enough information to either:

- allow the caller to do something useful with the exception, e.g., retry the operation, or
- assist the developer in understanding the problem and lead him/her to a resolution.

---

I'd encourage you to follow standard Java naming conventions to avoid confusing readers of your code: non-final variables should begin with a lower-case letter. Method names should also begin with lower-case letters.

Also, you do not need to preface methods (or variables) with `this` when there is no need to disambiguate the property you're accessing.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using VB.NET in my company, and our convention is like that. It needs time to follow Java standards. What about InsertOrThrow method? Does it throw exception or return -1 ? or both of them ?

Comment: @AhmetHüdaiAYDIN It will *either* return a value, *or* throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> When throw an exception how it has a return value? Something is wrong.

Yes, you're right. The documentation seems wrong.

`insertOrThrow` doesn't return `-1` , instead, it will throw `SQLException` if the query failed. There's a another method called `insert` which would return `-1` if the query failed, and newly created `rowID` if success.